# related to visualforce page getting images from godaddy

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce

Is It possible to get images from godaddy and use in visualforce page ,if it possible can You tell me syntax for that in visual force page.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the image tag and provide the image link from Godaddy site. It would not be a good idea as if godaddy changes the image link or remove that image it would affect your Vf page.

```
<apex:image id="theImage" value="https://img1.wsimg.com/pc/img/1/trademark/registered/gd_logo.png" width="220" height="55"/>
```